# Django composite forms - how do I build and save them?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to build a form that would provide report tracking. Report itself is `ProjectReport` class that links instances of all available `ReportAtoms`. Each `ReportAtom` is a combination of `RAGItem` (like "Progress", "Risks", "Resources") and `RAGMarker` ("Green", "Red"):

```
class ProjectStatus(CoreBase):
    report_project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
    report_items = models.ManyToManyField('RAGReportAtom')
    report_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

class RAGReportAtom(CoreBase):
    item = models.ForeignKey(DicRAGItem)
    marker = models.ForeignKey(DicRAGMarker)
    comments = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class DicRAGItem(DicCoreBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_used_for_portfolio = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_used_for_project = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_used_for_milestone = models.BooleanField(default=True

class DicRAGMarker(DicCoreBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    color_code = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
    icon = models.FileField(upload_to='RAG_SIMPLE_ICONS', null=True, blank=True)
```

This is how this can be represented graphically:

[image]

So what I am trying to do here is basically this:

1. Get list of all available report items (things reported on)
2. Build a form that will display all report items and let users select a marker for each
3. Users can leave comments
4. When form is submitted I create as many report atoms as I ended up having (combinations of items and markers) and a ProjectReport instance that links all them.

Something similar to this:

[image]

Is this going to be possible to generate this form with Django.forms and crispy? I am using django rest framework for most forms - perhaps I could make use of this, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't even need crispy forms to do that.

Formsets is the way to go ! [Official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/)

Basically it will look like :

```
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from myapp.models import ProjectReport
from myapp.forms import ReportAtomForm
# We use values() because initial data needs to be a dict
list_of_reports = ProjectReport.objects.get(id=key).report_items.values()
ReportAtomFormSet = formset_factory(ReportAtomForm)
formset = ArticleFormSet(initial=list_of_reports)
```

Then your view needs to handle the formset as described in the documentation. For the Marker and Item, they have to be Inline Formsets inside the ReportAtomForm as you can see here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: yeah, I figured the formset thing and it works - I get a form with two dropdowns (one pre-selected) and comments field - but how do I display one of the dropdowns as just text?

Comment: You mean you have 2 dropdown : marker and item, and you want markert to be a dropdown and item to be just the text representation of the item object ?
there is no direct way to do that with Django. The most direct way would be to override the __init__ method of ReportAtomForm to set a "item_name" property, and then display that in the Template. In the __int__ you can access the ReportAtom object through self.instance.
   def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.item_name = self.instance.item.name